# Infants with Jaundice: How does phototherapy's blue lights break down bilirubin?

Tags: infant, jaundice, bile, bilirubin

My **newborn** nephew was born as scheduled and by all accounts healthy. However, after a few days, it became apparent that he had **jaundice** and his **liver** was **not able to process/break-down the bilirubin** in the blood. Apparently, this is actually quite common for newborns since their livers are not fully formed, and they have more red-blood cells than adults do or whatever... (sorry, I'm not a health physician -- this is just my understanding from my sister-in-law). There was the possibility that if the jaundice didn't go away within a short period of time (with the help of special **formula**), that my nephew would have to **go under phototherapy (under intense blue lights).** See image below:

[image]

**How does phototherapy's blue lights break down bilirubin?**

*Fortunately, my nephew's jaundice cleared up on it's own, but I've been curious how phototheraphy works.*